# JavaScriptのプロトタイプチェーンについて

Tags: javascript

```
let Car = function(num, gas) {
      this.num = num;
      this.gas = gas;
};

Car.prototype = {
       getInfo: function() {
              return '車のナンバーは' + this.num + 'です。ガソリン量は' + this.gas + 'です。';
       }
};

let RacingCar = function(course) {
      Car.call(this, 2345, 30);
      this.course = course;
};

RacingCar.prototype = new Car();

RacingCar.prototype = {
        getCourse: function() {
                 return 'コースは' + this.course + 'です。';
        }
};

let rccar = new RacingCar(5);
console.log(rccar.getInfo());
console.log(rccar.getCourse());
```

上記のコードを実行すると、

> TypeError: rccar.getInfo is not a function

とエラーが出るのですが、何故プロトタイプチェーンが効かないのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！代入するタイミングが悪かったんですね。助かりました！

Comment: 質問者 さん> 解決されたようで良かったです。もし解決されたのであれば、回答の横側にあるチェックマークをクリックし、質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RacingCar.prototype` に対して **`new Car` を代入した直後で `getCourse` メソッドを持つオブジェクトを代入している**ためです。

```js
{
  let Car = function(num, gas) {
    this.num = num;
    this.gas = gas;
  };

  Car.prototype = {
    getInfo: function() {
      return '車のナンバーは' + this.num + 'です。ガソリン量は' + this.gas + 'です。';
    }
  };

  let RacingCar = function(course) {
    Car.call(this, 2345, 30);
    this.course = course;
  };

  RacingCar.prototype = new Car();

  RacingCar.prototype.getCourse = function() { // 修正
    return 'コースは' + this.course + 'です。';
  };

  let rccar = new RacingCar(5);
  console.log(rccar.getInfo()); //=> 車のナンバーは2345です。ガソリン量は30です。
  console.log(rccar.getCourse()); //=> コースは5です。
}
```